# Showing a point is a limit point of a set

Tags: real-analysis, fractals

For sake a clarity, when I say a "limit point", the definition I am using is:

> $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if there exists a sequence $\{x_k\}$ such that $x_k \neq x$ and $x_k \rightarrow x$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

(as opposed to the more general definition about a topological space).

---

My set up is as follows:
Let $E_0 = [0,1]$ and $E_{k+1}$ be constructed by removing the second, fifth and eighth tenths of $E_k$.  Then define $F = \cap_{k=0}^{\infty} {E_k}$.

I am trying to show that $0$ (zero) is a limit point of $F$.

As with these types of questions, I can see the intuition behind why this is true, but I'm struggling to actually prove it is true.  In particular, I'm struggling to figure out how to construct the sequence $\{x_k\}$.

My first thought was to try and construct the sequence using the maximum point of each $E_k$ at each step, but realised this wouldn't work for a variety of reasons; mainly that the points in this sequence were not in $F$ itself.  I guess what I'm struggling with most is how to formally construct the sequence, since I can't think of a `nice' way to define it properly.

Any help about how to construct this sequence, or a different method to try, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't $1/10^n \in F$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, it is.  

I was actually just about to delete this question since I realised that, in my earlier attempts, I was removing all but the second, fifth and eighth tenths, as opposed to keeping them.  Explains why I was having problems though.

Thanks for the reply in any case!

Comment: Cool - glad you got it! I don't have time to write a proper answer at the moment so delete away, if you like.  I don't see duplicate after a quick search, so I'd be inclined to leave it, though.